# Multivariate Generating Function Related to Lambert $W$ Function and Counting Trees with a Certain Property

Tags: co.combinatorics, special-functions, generating-functions, power-series, functional-equations

First, define a sequence $F_0,F_1,\dots$ of functions by
$$F_0(x,z) = z,$$
$$F_k(x,z)=x\exp\left(F_{k-1}(x,z)\right) \quad \text{for }k\geq1.$$
So, for example,
$$F_1(x,z) = x e^z, \quad F_2(x,z)=xe^{xe^z},\dots$$
etc. Also, set $F_{-1}(x,z)=0$. Now, let 
$$G(x,z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(F_k(x,z) - F_{k-1}(x,x)\right).$$
That is, 
$$G(x,z) = z + \left(xe^z - x\right)+\left(xe^{xe^z} - xe^x\right) + \dots$$

What I would like to do is to get some information (it doesn't have to be amazingly strong information...) about the asymptotics of the coefficient of the $x^{n-j}z^j$ term in the power series for $G(x,z)$.

**Question:**  Does anyone know whether I have any hope in extracting any information from this generating function? If so, any ideas about what I should do/try? Even a pointer to something in the literature which *might* help me would be great!

By the way, the function $G(x,z)$ is closely linked to the Lambert $W$ Function. In particular, (I think) it is not hard to see that
$$G(x,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1} x^n}{n!}$$
and it is well known that this function is the solution to the functional equation
$$G(x,x) = x\exp(G(x,x)).$$
The thing that makes this question tricky therefore seems to be the presence of the second variable, $z$.

**Remark:** By the way, the coefficient of $x^{n-j}z^j$ in
$$F_k(x,z)-F_{k-1}(x,x)$$
counts the number $n$-vertex trees rooted at vertex $1$ of height exactly $k$ such that there are exactly $j$ vertices at distance $k$ from the root. Therefore, the coefficient of $x^{n-j}z^j$ in $G(x,z)$ is the number of $n$-vertex trees (of any height) in which there are $j$ vertices at maximum distance from vertex $1$. If anyone knows anything about the number of such trees (independently of the generating function), then that would also be useful!

Comment: Did you take a look at "The average height of binary trees and other simple trees" by Flajolet and Odlyzko? https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00076505/document This is not exactly the same model, but might be relevant

Comment: @SergeyDovgal Thanks. Yes, I have come across that paper. This one https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700004432 by Renyi and Szekeres is actually even more relevant (in fact, the function $F_k(x,z)$ appears in that paper; see equation (2.9)). It looks to me like their methods probably can't be directly applied here. However, I'm not completely sure... I am not an expert in analytic methods and find their paper really tough to read... also the same goes for the Flajolet and Odlyzko paper... really tough.

Comment: The height $H_n$ of a random rooted Cayley tree with $n$ nodes is of
order $\sqrt{n}$, more precisely: the distribution of $H_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges
to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distribution as $n\longrightarrow \infty$. 
This is a special case of the results here http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1128044.

Comment: Perhaps... But this doesn't seem to tell me how many vertices are at maximum distance from the root.

Comment: (1) True, but it shows that the order of the no. of nodes at maximal height is not higher than $\sqrt{n}$.       
(2) It is plausible that $\sqrt{n}$ is the correct order, since by the results of Stepanov (see http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1114007)
and Meir&Moon (see https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1978-085-0) asymptotically each layer (stratum) at height $x\sqrt{n}$ of a rooted random
tree with $n$ nodes contains of order $\sqrt{n}$ nodes, moreover asymptotically a randomly chosen node lies at a height of order $\sqrt{n}$.
Question: how precise do you need this information to be made?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that a random tree would have $\sqrt{n}$ vertices in its highest level. If you think of it as a branching process (I don't claim that this is the correct intuition) it seems that, out of a set of $\sqrt{n}$ vertices, it is quite likely that at least one of them will have a child. I would actually guess that the average number of vertices in the last level converges to a constant as $n$ tends to infinity (but this is a guess). In particular, it might be the case that the probability that a random tree has $k$ vertices in the last level decays exponentially with $k$.

Comment: You're right (and my assumption above probably false).  The branching process perspective suggests that 
the limiting distribution of the no. of nodes in the highest level should be a discrete distribution concentrated on positive integers
(maybe even degenerate).
This might be known, if so, it can possibly be found in Pavlov's book "Random Forests". Else you'll have to analyse the g.f. yourself (using the saddle point
method). I would first try to find the asymptotic distribution of the number of nodes in height $k$ in a random tree of height $k$ for fixed $k$ and then try to
extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptotic distribution of the number of nodes at maximal height in a random tree is known.

The following was known as "Wilf's conjecture" (H. S. Wilf stated it in 1991, evidently unaware of the fact that it had been popularized among Russian combinatorialists
by V. F. Kolchin earlier):

Choose a labeled tree of $n$ vertices uniformly among all $n^{n-2}$ labeled
trees and let $L_n$ be the number of vertices at maximal graph distance from its 
root (the vertex with label $1$).
                                             Then $L_n$ converges in distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$,
i.e., there exists a probability distribution $(q_\ell)_{\ell\geq 1}$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}(L_n=\ell)\longrightarrow q_\ell,\;\;\ell\ge 1$$

This conjecture was settled by Kesten and Pittel in 1996, see 
[http://www.dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2418(199607)8:4<243::AID-RSA1>3.0.CO;2-Y](http://www.dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2418(199607)8:4%3C243::AID-RSA1%3E3.0.CO;2-Y)

Kesten and Pittel proved (Corollary 2, page 8) that the conjecture is true, and that  $$q_\ell=\pi_\ell e^{-\ell}$$
where $(\pi_\ell)_{\ell\geq 1}$ is the unique solution of 
$$\pi_\ell\geq 0,\;\;\;\;\pi_\ell=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \pi_k\,e^{-k}\frac{k^\ell}{\ell!},\;\;\;\,\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \pi_{\ell}e^{-\ell} =1$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reference! This may not answer my question 100%, but it is very useful to me :-).